# How to solve issue regarding debug compile classpath?

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, compiler-errors, configuration

I was building a navigation app according to the tutorial . [image]I am a beginner at learning kotlin. I am getting the following issue as shown in the pic. I don't even know what this issue is about.

Answer (score 0):

It is better that use `Gradle Plugin DSL` for binary plugins [see this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)
, for currently issue write follow snippet code in project level gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs") version "2.5.2" apply false
}
```

If the problem still persists, it is better to share the build.gradle module level code so that you can comment more precisely.